# Why should I use routing, what's wrong with normal links?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, url-routing

I've started to learn node.js and express, and I am curious what is the point of all this routing. Example:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home', blogs });

});

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {

    
    res.render('about', { title: 'About' });


});
```

What's wrong with normal `<a href>`tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal tag" ?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: Show the code for the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with any of the above, you are just mixing up things from different worlds.

Express.js routes are declarations for a server to instruct which code to execute when browser open your website on a particular url.

`<a href>` tags are used in HTML to instruct the browser where to navigate if user clicks it.

Giving your example:
If you have somewhere in your HTML `<a href="/about">About page</a.` and a user clicks it, then browser would navigate to the '/about' page.
Express.js will receive the new request from browser, render the "about" template, and return the rendered content back to user's browser.

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` HTML element (or anchor element), with its href attribute, creates a hyperlink to web pages, files, email addresses, locations in the same page, or anything else a URL can address.

**Express routes** if you want a simple answer are the place where you receice new request from users (browser), and determine how the server should respond to those requests.

and you need to put in your mind that **when a user clicks on a link `<a href`>**, **the browser send a new request to the server for the linked page**.

I hope I simplified the answer a bit, I hope you understand, I also had the same problem between these two things, but you will understand it more when you start a small project.

good luck,